# About $\sum \sin(\kappa \sin (\kappa \sin(\cdots \sin \kappa x)\cdots)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have proved that, given $|\kappa|<1$, the function:

$$f(x)=\sum_{n\geqslant 1} \underbrace{\sin(\kappa \sin (\kappa \sin (\cdots \sin}_n\, \kappa x)\cdots)$$

Is defined for all real $x$ (the series converges everywhere). My question is, what does the function look like? I don't have the software to plot it, and I can't figure it out on paper. Sorry if the question is a little vague.

Comment: Interesting question...

I guess that $\lim{k \rightarrow 0} = \sin(x)$... Also that $f(0) = 0$ and that $f(k\pi) = 0$ for all integer $k$

So perhaps something like

$$
f(x) = x^\alpha \prod_k \Big(1 - \frac{x^2}{k^2\pi^2} \Big)^\alpha
$$

Just a wild guess...

Comment: ^ zero's for case $\kappa=1$ (can't edit anymore...)

Comment: Plot sin(sin(sin(sin(sin(sin(sin(sin(x is given at Wolfram http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28sin%28sin%28sin%28sin%28sin%28sin%28sin%28x%29%29%29%29%29%29%29%29

Plot sin(sin(sin(sin(sin(sin(x/4)/4)/4)/4)/4)/4) is http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28sin%28sin%28sin%28sin%28sin%28x%2F4%29%2F4%29%2F4%29%2F4%29%2F4%29%2F4%29

Comment: The thing that is interesting is if $n \rightarrow 0$...

Then we can write

$$
f(z) = \sin \big(\kappa f(z) \big)
$$

and so

$$
f'(z) = \kappa \cos\big( \kappa f(z)\big) f'(z)
$$

but for $|\kappa| < 1$ we can only have $f(z) = 0$? What am I doing wrong???

Comment: @johannvalks be careful about the appearance of $x$ in your equation. Asymptotically, there is just 1 power of $x$ in the series, which means you should not have $x^n$ appearing for any $n$ larger than 1.

Comment: The last equation you just examined is basically telling us that the series passes $n$-th term test, since the limit should be 0.

Comment: It does look very close to $\frac{\sin(\kappa x)}{1-\kappa}$. following is a [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427eipjsdgp1ft) on WA with $\kappa = \frac13$ and truncate the sum up to $n = 10$.

Comment: In case above clip on WA disappear, you can plot the function on WA yourself using command `Plot[Sum[Nest[ (Sin[#/3])&, x, k],{k,1,10}],{x,0,Pi}]` Replace the $3$ by $\frac{1}{\kappa}$ you use and $10$ by the number of terms you want to keep in your sum.

Comment: @achillehui Very nice WA command. Also notice that $\sin(kx)/(1-k)$ is approximately $kx/(1-k)$ for small $x$. Which would correspond to the asymptotics I mentioned.

Comment: @Joel it is your answer that inspire me to compare $f(x)$ with $\frac{\sin(\kappa x)}{(1-\kappa)}$. Please note that in above plot, there are actually two curves!

Comment: So there are :) I am really not very good with computer algebra systems. I'm just stuck with pen and paper :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question asks for what the function *looks like*.  Sadly the answer is rather dull.  I used Geogebra to graph the first seven terms in the series and their sum for values of $\kappa$ that are controlled by a slider.  (Adding more terms does not seem to significantly change the appearance of the graph.)  That is, I plotted
$$f_1(x)=\sin(\kappa x)$$
$$f_2(x)=\sin(\kappa f_1(x))$$
$$f_3(x)=\sin(\kappa f_2(x))$$
$$\vdots$$
$$f_7(x)=\sin(\kappa f_6(x))$$
$$g(x)=f_1(x)+f_2(x)+\cdots +f_7(x)$$
The graph is shown below.  The blue curve is the sum; the black curves are the individual terms of the series.

[image]

Comment: how did you create the gif image?

Comment: Geogebra has "Animated GIF" as one of the format options under the "Export" menu command.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\sin(x)$ is approximately $x$ for small $x$, the tail of this function will behave a lot like $\sum_{n \ge 1} k^n x = \frac{xk}{1-k}$. This is of course a heuristic, but often it helps to think of $\sin(x)$ in this way.